# VM Tracker empty in Instruments

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, profiling, instruments

VM Tracker in Instruments is empty when trying to profile a certain app. I can analyze all other apps but this one is just showing empty.

I have the automatic snapshot on & doing a manual snapshot is not working.

I can't remember if there were any specific changes to this project that could make VM Tracker stop working.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it's working now. In schemes, I had the Release mode set for Profiling. Changed to Debug and now it works.